# Can a single bjt PNP be an or gate?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, pnp

I'm curious,  with a transistor being equivalent to two diodes,  could one wire a single PNP with a pull down diode to be an OR gate? My thinking is as follows:

[image]

Is this right, or wrong.  Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCdJqV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A tidy version of the OP's 'OR' gate.*

It might work in certain circumstances. The problem is that the base current affects the emitter-collector resistance.

- If A is high then an emitter-base current will flow.
- This will turn on Q1 and provide a low-resistance path between A and B.
- What happens next will depend on the output impedances of A and B. If they are the same then Q1 will tend to pull them together towards mid-supply voltage.

It's not going to work as you planned.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbbjvi.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Simulation circuit.*

Running a simulation using the CircuitLab tool results in the following readings for R1 = R2 at 1k and 100 Ω:

```
     1k         100 Ω
A    1.927 V    2.469 V
B    1.909 V    2.365 V
Q    1.163 V    1.663 V
```

Note that at lower source resistance the effect of R3 is less and A and B settle down close to mid-supply. Q is 0.7 V below the emitter voltage as would be expected.

Comment: +1 and you beat me by about 5 seconds. I'd add, if the OP is considering this for a quick and small fix that double diodes are available in the same sort of packages.

Comment: @Trevor what might that ic be called?

Comment: See https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds12003.pdf for an example. I've also updated my answer with sim results.

Comment: @tuskiomi "Dual diode-common cathode"